# Calling afterSave in custom module

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am stuck on what seems like a pretty straight-forward task: calling the afterSave method in a custom module that inherits from apostrophe-pieces. My objective is to make an XHR call any time my custom content type is created or updated. I've tried putting the call in /lib/modules/<my-module>/index.js (where I would think it would go) and /lib/modules/<my-module>/lib/api.js without luck. Thanks in advance for some guidance on this.

Comment: Hey Ken, can you post some post your `index.js` of your custom piece? (with attempted afterSave)

Comment: Thanks, Stuart. Here it is: https://gist.github.com/nodots/b41e14b4ccffb35e66fbeb84b7dd77bf

Answer (score 1):

You want to hook into `afterSave` from the module's `construct` method, I commented on your gist

https://gist.github.com/nodots/b41e14b4ccffb35e66fbeb84b7dd77bf

Comment: Yep, that's the right way — methods go inside `construct` where they can see `self`.